# Create multiple directories in different folders

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I want to create one folder for each preselected *.mkv-file in the corresponding subfolder, named after that *.mkv-file, e.g.:

```
Z:\1\1.mkv; Z:\2\2.mp4; Z:\3\3.mkv --> Z:\1\1 (additional folder);
Z:\1\1.mkv; Z:\2\2.mp4; Z:\3\3 (additional folder); Z:\3\3.mkv
```

```
$inputfiles = gci *.mkv -recurse

foreach ($file in $inputfiles) 
{
new-item -path Z:\* -name "$($file.BaseName)" -itemtype directory
}
```

Problem here is, that in each subfolder all of the directories are created, not just the corresponding one.

I also tried `-path $inputfiles` but got an error message.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: And after creating the subfolders, do you want to move the *.mkv files in there?

Comment: I want to unpack them with ffmpeg (mkv --> tiff), get the framemed5s and compare them with the framemd5s off the mkv

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you have added `\*` after the path for the New-Item.

Try:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.mkv' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # construct the path for the (new) subfolder
    $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path 'Z:\' -ChildPath $_.BaseName
    # create a new directory if not already existed
    $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory -Force

    # if you want the .mkv file to be moved to that new directory, uncomment the line below
    # $_ | Move-Item -Destination $targetFolder
}
```

<sup>The `-Force` switch on the New-Item line ensures it either creates a new directory or returns the folder object of an existing one without error messages.</sup>

Comment: Your suggested answer works fine. Unfortunately I need the new directories in the subfolder: e.g. _Z:\BaseName\_  , new folder  _Z:\BaseName\BaseName_. Sorry, if I wasn't precise enough in the initial request. I tried it with the Parameter `-AdditionalChildPath` but got an error message. Could you help again?

Comment: @user14245857 Can you edit your question and add an example of the current structure and below that what the desired structure should be? If I understand your comment correctly, you need to watch out for endless `\BaseName\BaseName\BaseName\BaseName\BaseName\BaseName\BaseName\BaseName` recursions..

Comment: @ Theo: I hope I edited my initial question good enough, thanks for your reply.